# Can I configure IIS to let my ASP.NET application alive forever?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, iis-7

As far as I know, an ASP.NET application ends whenever there's no user session alive, the default session time-out is 20 minutes. After that time it will go alive again when there's a new request.

However, my application performs a very slow cache loading operation on Application_Start and I don't want that to happen more than once.

**How can I configure IIS to act different?**

I learned the Application Pool on IIS 7.5 has a property called auto-start and other called idle-time-out. The documentation says that if I set auto-start to true and idle-time-out to zero than the application pool will start when IIS starts and never time out. But I don't know how it is integrated to ASP.NET. Does that mean Application_Start will run with IIS start and that it won't happen again until the next IIS restart?

Answer (score 2):

I use [uptime robot](http://www.uptimerobot.com/) to ensure my application is always spun up. The beauty of this 
 system is it only asks for the headers of a page on your website and gets status codes like "200-ok", "404-not found", etc. every 5 minutes. This means that uptime robot does not add noise to Google Analytics as the page is never requested.

Seems to work like a dream for me and its **FREE!**

Comment: I just added a monitor. If this prevents the AppPool from stopping I'll be very relieved!

Comment: App pool may stop for other reasons, memory exceeded etc... You may still see app pool recycle but hopefully this will limit it

Answer (score 1):

For the settings you describe for IIS 7.5:

There can be other reasons for an application pool to restart (e.g. it exceeding a memory usage limit).

But Application_Start will be run each time such a restart occurs. And, of cource, an administrator can always recycle an application pool.

So, if your question is specifically about a 1-1 relationship between IIS restarts and your application restarting, the answer is no. But in normal usage, with no mem leaks/horrific crashes, it should be approximately so.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET 4.0+ apps on IIS7.5+ - you can set up Auto-Start and move your startup code from the Application_Start in the global.asax into the Preload method of a class.  See this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

Here is an example using the IIS8 GUI: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/795265/IIS-Asp-net-warm-up-Auto-Start-Application